# Replace cells containing a specific value with multiple cells

Tags: excel

I am looking to replace one cell with multiple cells. Say I have a range of cells that contain various values, how would I select all that contain a specific value and put multiple cells of different values in its place?   For example, I have a range of cells each containing a single letter, A B C D A D. I have another range of cells each containing a single number 1 2 3 4 that I want to put in the place of A. My desired output would be

1 2 3 4 B C D 1 2 3 4 D

Let us assume all cell ranges are vertical

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Find/ replace only works for replacing a set of cells with one value. I am looking to replaces all cells containing a certain value with another set of cells. For instance I could be looking to replace every cell that contains A with a 3x1 range of cells that I have selected

Comment: Type in the value of those 3 cells into the replace field?? If you have numerous 3 cells, then you need to show code before asking for help.

Comment: So you want a function that takes a search string and a replacement range of cells and searches the entire worksheet for the search string and replaces it with the replacement range.  I understand how you want that to work if the replacement range is one row high (you just insert enough cells to hold the replacement)  But if it is more than one row high what do you do?  For example a 3x2 replacement range: do you insert empty an extra row for the second row of the replacement or do you insert cells in both rows moving stuff to the right in the row it was found and the row below it?

Comment: And what happens if the search string is A and the replacement is 1 2 A 3?  Should it know not to replace in the replacement range?  Or should it copy the replacement range first and then use the copy to do the replacement so that the original replacement range can be replaced?

Comment: If we insert cells so a multi row replacement will fit which direction do we move the cell at the bottom right hand corner of range where the replacement will land?  It could go to the right or down or both.  If we do insert the cells needed for the replacement do we insert entire rows and columns or just enough cells to hold the replacement?  Inserting entire rows and columns means that the data will continue to line up in tabular form but that may not be what you want...

Comment: Lets say I was replacing a cell by a 3x2 replacement range, the desired effect would be to push everything below the original cell down 3, out of the way. Essentially we would be inserting rows and the column width of the replacement range would not matter as it would go on to fill as far as it needs. The situation of the replacement cell appearing in the replacement range would not come up in my specific problem.